# How can I get PHPUnit to print inner exceptions?

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a way to get PHPUnit to print inner exceptions when something goes wrong?

Here's a simple example:

```
class TestTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    function test() {
        throw new Exception("Outer exception message", 0, new Exception("Inner exception message"));
    }
}
```

I want to see both messages but I only see the outer one.

Comment: [It already does](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.7/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php#L271-L273), provided you're using the default results printer. Are you wanting something else shown?

Comment: @bishop is right. It already does, but this way you can't test inner and outer exception message.

Comment: @bishop, I put a breakpoint at that line of code and it was never called. I have no listeners defined in my config file.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I sometimes have a catch block that catches generic exceptions thrown by some library or other and throws an exception that has a more informative message. When I do this, I still want to see the full stack trace. The outer exception is usually also of a different type. That tells me at a glance what part of my application needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes, I am of the opinion that exceptions should lead to code fixes where applicable.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I don't need to test the inner exception messages. I consider inner exceptions to be an implementation detail. I just need to see it for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

1. Decorator pattern is helpful.

```php
class OuterDecoratorException extends \Exception {

  private $innerException;

  public function __construct(string $message, \Exception $innerException) {
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->innerException = $innerException;
  }

  public function __toString(): string {
    return \sprintf(
      "Outer: %s Inner: %s",
      $this->getMessage(),
      $this->innerException->getMessage()
    );
  }

}



throw new OuterDecoratorException("Outer message", new \Exception("Inner message"));
```

**2. Prefer over a decorator, direct compilation of exception message in every test.**

```php
class TestTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    function test() {

        throw new \Exception(
            sprintf(
                "Inner: %s Outer: %s",
                "Inner message",
                 (new \Exception("Outer message"))->getMessage()
            ),
            0
        );
    }
}
```

3. Otherwise you must extends a library. See manual - how to extends a framework.

Comment: Then I would lose the stack trace of the inner exception.

Comment: This would also wreak havoc with the way that I handle exceptions in my application.

Answer (score -1):

[PHPUnit already supports this.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.7/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php#L271-L273)

```
$ cat TestTest.php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class TestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function test() {
        throw new Exception("Outer exception message", 0, new Exception("Inner exception message"));
    }
}

$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit TestTest.php
PHPUnit 5.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 57 ms, Memory: 4.25MB

There was 1 error:

1) TestTest::test
Exception: Outer exception message

/tmp/TestTest.php:7

Caused by
Exception: Inner exception message

/tmp/TestTest.php:7

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

That it doesn't suggests your environment isn't booting properly. I suspect it's because you're using *namespaces*, which IIRC, PHPUnit doesn't support. Change `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` to `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.